# Access implicitly typed variable outside the block

Tags: c#, implicit-declaration

Im trying to declare a variable as an object which returns an anonymous type object. I get an error like (cannot implicitly convert type Anonymous1 to Anonymous2.

```
var queryResult = new object();

            if (check == 1)
            {
                queryResult = context.SubjectContext
                    .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == CreatedBy)
                    .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name });
            }
            else (check == 2)
            {
                queryResult = context.SubjectContext
                    .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == CreatedBy)
                    .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name, x.Skillset });
            }


            if (queryResult.Any())
            {
                return jsonRetrunMsg = new JsonReturn { Status = "success", Message = queryResult };
            }
            else
            {
                return jsonErrorMsg = new JsonError { Status = "error", Message = "Check User Id" };
            }
```

Comment: Obviously your both anonymous types are different. they have different number of properties

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I have a main class from where Im selecting fields anonymously. I only need few for each request (different types of fields for each request). In addition I have multiple types of requests.

Comment: Could you provide a *fake* result so that anonymous types will match? Something like (in first query): `.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name, FakeSkillSet })`

Comment: I wonder why this was down voted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are selecting from the same context, in this case 'SubjectContext', you are creating a new type, when doing this:

```
.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name });
```

and this;

```
.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name, x.Skillset });
```

So, in this case, you have to return to an implicity-typed variable, known as 'var'. Something like this:

```
var queryResult = context.SubjectContext
        .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == CreatedBy)
        .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name });
```

Of course, in this case - which you are using it between the brackets -, you have to change the declaration of the 'queryResult', and control the result, before returning. Something like this:

```
   if (check == 1)
   {
        var queryResult = context.SubjectContext
            .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == CreatedBy)
            .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name });

        if (queryResult.Any())
        {
            return jsonRetrunMsg = new JsonReturn { Status = "success", Message = queryResult };
        }
        else
        {
            return jsonErrorMsg = new JsonError { Status = "error", Message = "Check User Id" };
        }

    } else if (check == 0)
    {
        var queryResult = context.SubjectContext
            .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == CreatedBy)
            .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name, x.Skillset });

        if (queryResult.Any())
        {
            return jsonRetrunMsg = new JsonReturn { Status = "success", Message = queryResult };
        }
        else
        {
            return jsonErrorMsg = new JsonError { Status = "error", Message = "Check User Id" };
        }
    }
```

In this case, the var queryResult will assume the type of the returned/created type in your Linq Query, and the error will not occour.

Well, reading the comments, i came to another solution for you, i guess it'll work, just give it a shot.

```
using System.Collections;
object queryResult;
        if (check == 1)
        {
            queryResult = context.SubjectContext
                .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == CreatedBy)
                .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name });

        } else if (check == 0)
        {
            queryResult = context.SubjectContext
                .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == CreatedBy)
                .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name, x.Skillset });
        }

        if ((queryResult != null) && ((queryResult as ICollection).Count > 0))
        {
            return jsonRetrunMsg = new JsonReturn { Status = "success", Message = queryResult };
        }
        else
        {
            return jsonErrorMsg = new JsonError { Status = "error", Message = "Check User Id" };
        }
```

Guess you can think about something to avoid this lot of code, but, it'll works for now.
Victor.

Comment: Ive implemented this at first actually. Im trying to make it short because Ive more than 10 check condition. In this case I cannot write the way u suggested.

Comment: I implemented another solution. Give it a shot =)

Comment: Im getting a null reference exception at queryResult as ICollection

Comment: Finally I resolved it. I missed out the else { queryResult = null } and in the - if (queryResult != null) { //..}

Comment: Have you tried with a query which returns at least one result? I edited my answer, to avoid the exception, btw.

Comment: Its same as Ive written still Ill vote up your response.

Comment: Instead of ((queryResult as ICollection).Count > 0) if use this you can get rid of null point exception -> ((queryResult as IQueryable<object>).Any())

Comment: @user2412230 Actually im testing if the queryResult is not null. So, it won't happen to throw an exception. Also, nice point, using the IQueryable. I'll give it a shot =)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you create a class since they have similarities on field

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Skillset { get; set; }
}
```

and your code will be like this.

```
object queryResult;

if (check == 1)
{
    queryResult = context.SubjectContext
        .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == CreatedBy)
        .Select(x => new Student() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name });
}
else (check == 2)
{
    queryResult = context.SubjectContext
        .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == CreatedBy)
        .Select(x => new Student() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, Skillset = x.Skillset });
}

if (queryResult.Any())
{
    return jsonRetrunMsg = new JsonReturn { Status = "success", Message = queryResult };
}
else
{
    return jsonErrorMsg = new JsonError { Status = "error", Message = "Check User Id" };
}
```

Comment: I have a main class from where Im selecting fields anonymously. I only need few for each request (different types of fields for each request). In addition I have multiple types of requests.

Comment: if that will be the case maybe you can just change "var queryResult = new Obj();" to "object queryResult;".. hopefully you will not get error on this.

Comment: I works when I initialize it - object queryResult = new object();
However, at the bottom - if (queryResult.Any()) { //execute } I get an error object doesnt contain def 'ANY' How can I check whether queryResult has value in it or not?